# Issues with managed package visibility?

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata, tooling-api, versioning

## Question

Is anyone experiencing issues with incorrect managed package apex class visibility?  Suddenly unable to save a class and everything seems to be in order.  What am I missing?  Anyone run into this or have workarounds?

## Update

Seems like this is an issue with the Tooling API.  Was using Sublime Text 3 + Maven's Mate, and switching from Tooling to Metadata apex compilation (which I seem to do daily now) resolved the issue.

## Background

Editing a class that refers to a Zuora class.

```
Zuora.OnDemandSyncManager syncManager = new Zuora.OnDemandSyncManager();
```

Previously this had saved fine, but now I'm getting the following error

```
Package Visibility: Type is not visible: ondemandsyncmanager
```

However the constructor is listed as global when I view the installed package components (v2.4)

[image: Managed Package Components]

Which matches the version settings for my class.

[image: Class Meta File]

Comment: Anyone know how to keep images from MBP retina's from looking so huge in stack exchange? Another Q?  [S.M]]

Comment: I've noticed the Tooling API (using MavensMate) has issues with managed packages. I couldn't compile a class for example, that was named the same as something in a managed package in my instance (i.e. the compiler wasn't considering the namespace difference).

Comment: I wonder if this is a MM issue or whether it's a tooling API issue

Comment: I think it is a tooling issue - I add the same problem a while back with this happening in the Dev Console. I reported it to support, but the odd thing was that it worked in another org on NA15 with the same package. I think I ended up removing the package and re-installing it, and it worked after that...

Comment: You can set MM to use the metadata API, there's a config file option. Fixed a number of odd errors for me.

Comment: @ca_peterson i've been doing a lot of that, if mm misbehaves with one api i'll switch to the other.  On average it seems everything i want to do will work with one or the other.

Comment: Upvoting.  I had a similar issue when trying to save a class depending on global classes in a package.  Saving through the UI worked fine.  I haven't tried yet, but I'm guessing if I update MavensMate to use the metadata API instead, it should work.

Comment: @JamesLoghry this may actually be an issue with maven's mate (if you're using that), the tooling api (at the time of the posting) didn't have documentation for how to set the api versions for related managed packages, although you could infer it from looking at the tooling api wsdl. Hence a lot of tools, i.e. maven's mate just didn't send that info which may be why this error message keeps happening. The metadata api doesn't have this issue, so seems to work better.

Comment: I've had this issue both with the Eclipse IDE & the dev. console, it doesn't appear to be a MM issue

Comment: @DavinC good to know, guess doc issues can affect everyone ;)

Comment: I am using MavensMate.  I switched to the Metadata api, but I'll more often get "Read Timeout" errors now for some reason. Damned if you do, damned if you don't as "they" say.

Comment: Lol, so true, I've had some of those come up recently, if you get them consistently, do post their issues list on github, they work on that a LOT, but things behave strangely out in the wild of salesforce land.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on user comments this appears to be a bug in the Tooling API.  Switching to a tool that uses the Metadata API resolves the issue (maven's mate w/config changes OR eclipse OR ant)

**Update**

So it's not a bug per se, more of a doc issue. The tooling api docs don't specify how to set the api versions for managed packages (at least at this time), although you can infer how to do it by looking at the tooling api wsdl. Because of this some tools, i.e. MM doesn't set the api versions for managed packages when updating apex classes ...

Comment: FWIW, this is a problem in the Developer Console too. I can't believe this hasn't been fixed yet. :-/ Similar stackexchange Q: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13184/developer-console-and-package-visibility-error

Comment: 1 yr later, still not available in the dev console, still finicky in mm ... errr